# Can I put project using premium theme on github as public?

Tags: licensing, mit, github, open-source-definition

I am not very familiar with github and license copyright. I purchase [metronic admin dashboard theme](https://keenthemes.com/metronic/) and built one project using it. So can I put this project on github as public so that others will be able to see it? Is this good decision? Or is this violation to Metronic theme privacy policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the associated licence summary](https://themeforest.net/licenses/terms/regular), when you purchase a regular licence

> You are licensed to use the Item to create one single End Product for yourself or for one client (a “single application”), and the End Product can be distributed for Free.
>   [...]
>   You can’t re-distribute the Item [...] with source files.

So putting it on github strikes me as a bad idea.  It would be pointless, anyway, because nobody else is allowed to copy the source, or modify it to create a different product (without buying their own licence).  This is not free software, nor can it be used to create free software; only zero-cost software, which is something completely different.

If you want to make free software, don't embed this product in it.  If you don't, your question's off-topic for this site.